# Is it okay to arrive in Europe with less than 400EUR?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, europe, money, switzerland

I'm Brazilian, travelling to Switzerland **as tourist** and I'll stay for **22 days** travelling around Europe. I don't need a visa.

I'm carrying with me only 400EUR but I made a transfer using **TransferWise** to a friend that I'll visit in the third day of this trip.

1. Should I carry with me the TransferWise receipt to present?
2. And it will be legal?

Comment: It's up to the border guards to decide if they are convinced you have sufficient means to cover your expenses, the laws and regulations do not go as far as listing specific types of transfer or anything like that. Also, at this point, the money isn't really yours, it's in your friend's control so evidence of the transfer might not be all that convincing. OTOH, it's probably not going to be an issue. Do you have a return ticket with you? Evidence of your professional situation back home?

Comment: Where are you from, do you need a visa?

Comment: A letter from your friend confirming that he'll give you the money you transferred to him will be much more valuable than a receipt for the transfer (the money belongs to our friend at the moment).

Comment: As for legal, if the transfer is above 10 000 EUR and you show a receipt of that at the border expect to be there for a long, long time.

Comment: I've landed in Nettherlands, Spain, Turrkey, Italy, Iceland, Wales, and several other non-EU countries and crossed by car, ferry, or bus into Ireland, France, Switzerland, and a few other EU countries.  ONLY U.K. asked about money, and I didn't have to show them anything; just told them I was carrying no cash but had three cards that would work in ATMs.

Comment: @chx hahaha it's about 2.000EUR

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I don't need visa, I'm Brazilian.

Answer (score 6):

The bad news is that some Brazilians went through the taxing, unpleasing experience of being sent back home directly from the airport, although they did not have a need for a visa. There's a small but well established community of illegal immigrants in countries like the UK or Spain. So, both countries will scrutinize you closer.

Take an **international** credit card with you, if possible. Otherwise, the 400 euros would be definitely too little. That's 18 euros/day.

If you are young, make sure you have a way of explaining why you would want to come back. Are you working, studying?

If you are visiting someone who is illegally in the EU, don't even mention this visit.

Don't bring anything that a tourist won't really need. They can go through your luggage and inspect any single item. So, do **not** carry family photos, CVs, clothes for a year, any Brazilian food, addresses of companies, and so on. All these things could raise a red flag.

Answer all questions at the border in a concise but precise manner. They don't want you to tell a little story, just basic facts. Sometimes border control agents start doing some small talk. Do not assume that they are just being friendly, they want to get information from you in an informal way.

Do not lie about anything. Often they already know the answer to the questions, and are just testing you.

Answer (score 1):

I know many people who have traveled to the Schengen area without a lot of cash and none of them have ever been required to demonstrate a proof of funds. Millions of people travel with just their credit card these days, so they won't be able to show any cash anyway.

What I would do is say you have 400 Euros in cash and have the rest in your bank account. No need to explain your story about Transferwise as that would just complicate things. I presume you do have money in your bank back at home, so this won't be a lie.

Comment: its tough though, Brasillians get extra scrutiny ....  :/  which sucks.